# Regex for line without runs of non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to regex to match e.g. the below string:

> Discover - CashBack Bonus & Citi TYP®

All of the non-alphanumeric characters like `-` , `&` and `®` , cannot appear one after another.

Tried this: `^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+[-]*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+[&]*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+[®]*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger `.*` doesn't match *every* string, since it doesn't match [line terminator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt) characters (by default).

Comment: *All of the non alphanumeric characters... cannot appear one after another*. Then just reject anything containing `[^A-Za-z0-9]{2,}`. But note that `" & "` is also an invalid sequence.

Comment: @shmosel can you write the entire regex?

Comment: That is the entire regex.

Comment: This only matches - and &

Comment: No, it matches 2 or more consecutive non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

> Tried this: `^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+[-]*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+[&]*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+[®]*[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$`

This didn't match because the trailing `[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$` requires 1 character of `[A-Za-z0-9 ]` at the end of the line, while your string ends with `®`.

To match a *line without runs of non-alphanumeric characters* except space, you can use the regex:

```
^.?([A-Za-z0-9 ]++.?)*$
```

This is essentially

- `[A-Za-z0-9 ]++` - a run of alphanumeric characters or space, followed by
- `.?` - at most one extra character,
- `(…)*` - the above occuring any number of times.

The leading `^.?` is there to allow for one extra character at the start of the string. And it's important to use the [*possessive quantifier*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `++` in order to avoid [*catastrophic backtracking*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).